# Resultant string utilising puts and strcat showing extra characters

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char c='g';
    char d[]="John ";
    strcat(d,&c);
    puts(d);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
John gC
```

The 'C' wasn't required.

Also, what does `const char*` mean here?

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)
```

Also, is a statement like this (inside a loop) wrong somewhere if I wish to add a character at the end of string?

```
char arr[]=' ';
symb[]={'a','b','c'}
strcat(arr, &symb[k]);
k++;
```

Comment: You are writing beyond the end of `d`, Your results will be *undefined* (like a box of chocolates...) Look at `man 3 strcat`, specifically "*if dest is not large enough*" How about `char d[32] = {0}; strcpy (d, "John ");` then `strcat`.

Comment: `char c` is a character, not a string. strcat only works with strings, hence the "str" prefix.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP thinks C is a real high-level language with a real string type.   Yes, it's array bounds/null-terminator  again;(

Answer (score 1):

You are writing out of the bounds of `d`, you need room for one more `char`, change to

```
char d[7] = "John ";
```

or (if you don't want to specify the size of the array):

```
char d[] = "John \0";
```

or

```
char d[] = {'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', ' ', '\0', '\0'};
```

Also `strcat` wants a valid NUL terminated string and you are passing a pointer to a single `char`, change to

```
char *c= "g";
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways(there are even more):-

1>

```
char *c="g";
char d[10]="John ";
strcat(d,c);
```

2>

```
char c[]="g";
char d[10]="John ";
strcat(d,c);
```

Though I advise  d[10] = {0} ; and then copy the string. (as David mentioned in comments.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn the basics of C and C-style strings. Specifically, that a special zero-value character identifies the end of the string.

You have copied over the string but you did not copy the terminator. Therefore, functions like `puts()` don't know when to stop and print other characters that happen to be in memory.

Answer (score 0):

This works: ( if you wanted John g )

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main()
    {
    char c='g';
    char d[10];
    char temp[2];

    strcpy(d ,"John ");
    temp[0]=c;
    temp[1]='\0';

    strcat( d , temp );


    puts(d);
    return 0;
    }
```

This works: ( if you wanted Johng )

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
char c='g';
char d[]="John ";
//strcat(d,&c);
d[strlen(d)-1]=c;

puts(d);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is *undefined behaviour*  in your program .  `strcat` requires `null terminated` string as its arguments where `c` is not . You can do this-

```
char c[]="g";    
char d[7]="John ";         // leave space for 'g' as well as for '\0'
strcat(d,c);              // then pass both to strcat
```

Another way is to use `sprintf` -

```
char c[]="g";
char d[10]="John";
size_t n =strlen(d);
sprintf(&d[n]," %s",c);
```